# Remove link to child association from list view in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a two rails `models` associated with `has_many` relationship. Inside the `list view` of `parent` model all the `child` records are listed with links to those records. I want the list to be rendered as is but without any `link`.

Eg. `Test` has many `Field`. In list view of `Test`, for each `Test` I would like to see the comma separated list of `Field` items but without links.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use `pretty_value` like this:

```
  config.model Test do
    list do
      field :fields do
        pretty_value do
          bindings[:object].fields.map(&:name).join(", ")
        end
      end
    end
```